# Can't run test in arquillian and glassfish

Tags: glassfish, jboss-arquillian, glassfish-embedded

I'm trying to deploy my EJB ear file to embedded glassfish server with Arquillian.

Here is my project structure.

- Parent Module
  -- EAR Module (maven-ear plugin creates the ear file)
  -- UI Module
  -- EJB Module (has dependencies to Entities, Utilities & reports module and the one that I have to test)
  -- Entities Module
  -- Utilities Module
  -- Reports Module
  -- WebServices Module
- Integration Test module (Arquillian, Glassfish 3.1 Integration tests)

This is how the Ear file is structured in the EAR module using maven-ear-plugin

- ejb.jar
- ui.war
- webservices.war
  -- Lib Folder
  --- utilities.jar
  --- entities.jar
  --- Plus other jars

All I'm trying to figure out is how to create a Ear file using Arquillian using ShrinkWrap to test just the ejb.jar which depends on utilites.jar, entities.jar and reports.jar.

```
@Deployment
public static EnterpriseArchive createTestArchive() {
    MavenDependencyResolver resolver = DependencyResolvers.use(
            MavenDependencyResolver.class).loadMetadataFromPom("pom.xml");

    EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class, "test.ear").
            addAsLibraries(resolver.artifact("<artifactid:groupid>").
            resolveAsFiles());

    return ear;
}

@Test
public void testInjection() {
    Object obj = new Object ();
    Objec .setName("TESO1");
    Object result = service.save(null, null, null);
    assertNotNull(result);
}
```

I've even tried putting ejb.jar, utilities.jar and entity.jar into a war file and deploying it but I can't get through this error. The deploy works fine ... the server starts up fine but the test fails saying no results returned

```
http://localhost:8181/test/ArquillianServletRunner?outputMode=serializedObject&className=mjs.ejb.MyBeanIT&methodName=testInjection. No result returned
```

I've also tried the code in this forum https://community.jboss.org/thread/203023?tstart=0 to add ejb.jar as a module and other dependencies as lib. But I still keep getting the following error. My ejb.jar has the persistence.xml file so I don't need to add any in my testcase (i think!). I do not add any config files in my ear file as you can see in my test case.

---

### Test set: mjs.ejb.MyBeanIT

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 21.601 sec <<< FAILURE!
testInjection(mjs.ejb.MyBeanIT)  Time elapsed: 1.234 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching test mjs.ejb.MyBeanIT public void     mjs.ejb.MyBeanIT.testInjection()
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:126)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:120)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:111)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$6.evaluate(Arquillian.java:263)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:226)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:234)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:133)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:114)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:188)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:166)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74) 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching request at http://localhost:8181/test/ArquillianServletRunner?outputMode=serializedObject&className=mjs.ejb.MyBeanIT&methodName=testInjection. No result returned
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.executeWithRetry(ServletMethodExecutor.java:162)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.invoke(ServletMethodExecutor.java:122)
... 81 more
```

Please help

Comment: Do you really call the resolver by  ´resolver.artifact("<artifactid:groupid>")´ instead of supplying your actual artifactid and groupid?

Comment: Can you please provide the full source code of your test class? You only add libraries to your EAR. Futhermore you don't add the test itself to the EAR. A complete example is easier to analyze.